# Summing dataframe over combinations of index columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with different sections (only 2 sections and speeds here, but a circuit can be up to 8 sections and 6 measured speeds) like so:

| section | speed | Data1 | Data2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 1.5 | 2.5 |
| A | 20 | 1.0 | 2.0 |
| B | 10 | 2.5 | 3.5 |
| B | 20 | 2.0 | 3.0 |

I would like to sum my data columns over all possible circuits

| A | B | Data1 | Data2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 10 | 4.0 | 6.0 |
| 10 | 20 | 3.5 | 5.5 |
| 20 | 10 | 3.5 | 5.5 |
| 20 | 20 | 3.0 | 5.0 |

How would I do this?  I can make the combinations, but not sure how to sum the data columns over them.

Comment: Do you have only A and B? If more would you want all combinations?

Comment: Yes, that's where it would get difficult.  You can have sections A-H and up to 6 different speeds for each.  `2**2` is simple, `8**6` is not trivial :P

Comment: OK, I think I see

Comment: are you looking for an answer on how to convert table A into Table B, and then calculate the sum, or from table B calculate just calculate the sums? Also, please confirm if you are looking for an answer to consider all possible 8 sections and then calculate Data1 and Data2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using `itertools.product`, then summing per group:

```
from itertools import product

df2 = df.set_index(['section', 'speed']).T

out = (pd.concat({k: df2[list(k)].sum(1)
                  for k in product(*(d for _,d in df2.groupby(axis=1, level=0)))})
         .unstack(level=-1)
      )
```

output:

```
                 Data1  Data2
(A, 10) (B, 10)    4.0    6.0
        (B, 20)    3.5    5.5
(A, 20) (B, 10)    3.5    5.5
        (B, 20)    3.0    5.0
```

For the exact provided format:

```
df2 = df.set_index(['section', 'speed']).T

sections = df2.columns.get_level_values('section').unique()

out = (pd.concat({tuple(x[1] for x in k):
                  df2[list(k)].sum(1)
                  for k in product(*(d for _,d in df2.groupby(axis=1, level=0)))
                 })
         .unstack(level=-1)
         .rename_axis(sections).reset_index()
      )
```

output:

```
    A   B  Data1  Data2
0  10  10    4.0    6.0
1  10  20    3.5    5.5
2  20  10    3.5    5.5
3  20  20    3.0    5.0
```

Comment: Can't wrap my head around either answer,  and both work, but the first multi-index output is slightly more useful for my application.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi @mozway, can you help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73039690/pandas-count-number-of-consecutive-rows-that-are-greater-than-current-row-valu

Answer (score 3):

One approach:

```
from itertools import product

groups = [[row for i, row in v.iterrows()] for _, v in df.groupby("section")]
rows = []
for p in product(*groups):
    row = {}
    for e in p:
        d = e.to_dict()
        row[d.pop("section")] = d.pop("speed")
        for k, v in d.items():
            row[k] = row.get(k, 0) + v
    rows.append(row)

res = pd.DataFrame(rows)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
    A  Data1  Data2   B
0  10    4.0    6.0  10
1  10    3.5    5.5  20
2  20    3.5    5.5  10
3  20    3.0    5.0  20
```

Or more *pythonic*:

```
def build_row(prod):
    row = {}
    for e in prod:
        d = e.to_dict()
        row[d.pop("section")] = d.pop("speed")
        for k, v in d.items():
            row[k] = row.get(k, 0) + v
    return row


groups = [[row for i, row in v.iterrows()] for _, v in df.groupby("section")]
res = pd.DataFrame([build_row(p) for p in product(*groups)])
print(res)
```

Note that if you want exact output, just reorder the columns.

Answer (score 0):

use pandasql package

```
df1.sql("""
    select a,b,tb1.data1+tb2.data1 as Data1,tb1.data2+tb2.data2 as Data2
        from
        (select speed as A,data1,data2 from self where section = 'A') tb1
        join
        (select speed as B,data1,data2 from self where section = 'B') tb2
""")
```

out：

```
    A   B  Data1  Data2
0  10  10    4.0    6.0
1  10  20    3.5    5.5
2  20  10    3.5    5.5
3  20  20    3.0    5.0
```